# How to rename a column name which has been created by a math function in mysql? Using ALTER TABLE is giving ERROR: 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql, alter-table, rename

INPUT:

```
CREATE TABLE dist
-> SELECT ST_DISTANCE(POINT(x1,y1),POINT(x2,y2))
-> FROM config;
```

OUTPUT:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| ST_DISTANCE(POINT(x1,y1) , POINT(x2,y2)) |
+------------------------------------------+
|                        140.0071426749364 |
|                       139.30183056945089 |
|                        138.6001443000692 |
|                       137.90213921473443 |
|                       137.20787149431334 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

RENAME COLUMN INPUT

```
> ALTER TABLE dist
-> RENAME COLUMN ST_DISTANCE(POINT(x1,y1),POINT(x2,y2)) TO Values;
```

> ERROR: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(POINT(x1,y1),POINT(x2,y2)) TO Values' at line 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides that Values is a very bad choice for a column name, as are all reserved words

You can give the column a name by creation. like

```
CREATE TABLE dist (`Values` DECIMAL(12,11))
 SELECT ST_DISTANCE(POINT(x1,y1),POINT(x2,y2)) as 'values'
 FROM config;
```

Comment: Hi, I had already tried that. It adds another column "values" will NULL for each of the value. And the ST_DISTANCE column remains the same with same column name.

Comment: @Titiksha  i changed myanswer after testing it with mysql 8.0.25

Comment: Thanks, this worked

Comment: Don't forget to [accept the answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Use backtics around the expression (which is the column name in the new table.)

```
ALTER TABLE dist
    RENAME COLUMN `ST_DISTANCE(POINT(x1,y1),POINT(x2,y2))` TO Values;
```

Note `RENAME COLUMN` was added in 8.0 and 10.5; if you have an older version, you must use the more verbose `CHANGE COLUMN` syntax.

(Oh, and be cautious about `VALUES`; it may be a reserved word.)